# Using Visual Studio 2015 diagnostic tool to examine memory usage

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8.1, uwp

So VS2015 has a cool new Diagnostic tool which shows memory and CPU usage while debugging, which should be very useful. However I'm having some confusion while using it. 
I'm writing a Windows 8.1 XAML app, started with a blank template, I just hit F5 and the Diagnostic tool showed memory usage of 25MB (Process memory), so far so good.
After I started playing around with the code a bit (just some setups, no business logic, no networking, no images yet), I ran the code again and this time the tool showed memory usage of 35MB, which scared me a bit. So I tried running the profiling tool and it showed only about 50KB in the managed heap.
[image]

To add to the confusion, when I checked with the Task manager, it showed that my process was taking up only 16MB[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSDNG.jpg)

What can be an explanation to all this and what figure should I believe in?

Comment: Since you opened the *Managed Heap* tab, I assume, that you are using the .NET framework. As far as the OS is concerned, the managed heap contributes to a process' private bytes, even when the memory is not currently used by the application. To get more accurate memory consumption information, you'd have to ditch the .NET framework in favor of an unmanaged programming environment (e.g. C++/CX).

Comment: More details, particularly with respect to the managed heap, can be found at [Diagnosing memory issues with the new Memory Usage Tool in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My "Heap" tab showed about 2.8MB Baseline. Funny thing is, I tried to stop most of the allocations (including the Frame itself) but the memory figure didn't go down. I also found the Windows Task Manager not very reliable.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  Task Manager shows *working set*, the amount of RAM you use.  The profiler shows *private bytes*, the amount of virtual memory you use for storage that isn't shared.  The managed heap only applies to .NET allocations.  A UWP program will use lots of unmanaged memory, everything that's in your XAML, the underlying code was written in C++.  35 MB is peanuts.

Comment: Hans Passant is correct. Most of the memory an UWP application uses is allocated on the unmanaged heap. The managed heap only stores managed objects, including COM proxies like RCW and CCW's to the unmanaged XAML objects.